# How to repeat a google script function on every row in a column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google app script, that clears cells L2 and M2 if there is a change in cell B2.

I would like to apply this to the whole range of B2:B in case of change, it should clear the cell that matches their row. So for example if there is a change in B5, it should clear L5 and M5.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction? I just searched through here for 1h and couldn't make it happen.

Many thanks!

```
function onEdit(e){

  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "B2" && 
      e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet3"
) 
     e.source.getRange("L2").clear() &&
      e.source.getRange("M2").clear()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the row from range ([See getRow() method from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)), and you could use it directly, like:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "B"+row && e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet3") 
  {
    e.source.getRange("L"+row).clear();
    e.source.getRange("M"+row).clear();

  }
}
```

But your code only handle single cell selection. Here is a evolution, handling multiple cell selection:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  // Check if column B and sheet "Sheet3"
  if(range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet3") 
  {
    if(range.getHeight()>1)
    {
      // Multiple cells selection case
      var nbRow = range.getNumRows();
      var i;
      for(i =0; i < nbRow; i++)
      {
        var temp = row + i;
        e.source.getRange("L"+temp).clear();
        e.source.getRange("M"+temp).clear();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // One cell selection case
      e.source.getRange("L"+row).clear();
      e.source.getRange("M"+row).clear();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Merci 1000x je t'achèterais une bouteille de vin pour te remercier, mais je sais pas comment te l'envoyer! :)